# Set textbox to "nothing" in WPF but MV value not updated

Tags: wpf, textbox

I have a user interface where a user can enter a value and that value is updated in the ViewModel (and eventually written back to a database).

This works fine if the a value is actually entered.  But if you want to clear that value (i.e. set it to nothing) it doesn't seem to work.

So for example if it was 'dog' but I clear that text and "save" the change is not recognized.

I call "PropertyChanged" which is fired if a value is entered.  But if the text is cleared, and I hit enter or tab out of the textbox, the property is not updated.

Is there some special way to deal with this or am I just missing something?

thanks

Comment: Did you check the database once you've cleared the text and lost focus? Have you set any UpdateSourceTrigger to your textbox or is it default? If you've set it to PropertyChanged, it fires whenever your text changes. You clear the textbox, the PropertyChanged would've been fired and when you lose focus it will not because the property is the same. However if the db itself is not updated, then there should be some other problem.

Comment: I am having the same difficulties - with basic string - no database just evaluating the viewmodel.  When I set the viewmodel property to blank via a button command, my validation no longer takes effect either

Answer (score 1):

It ought to work....

Are you sure your other layers (especially the DB) accept 'empty' values? It could be a conversion-exception or error being silently eaten.

To diagnose, experiment with different properties of different types.

Answer (score 1):

The property will not be updated if the data type is an int. 
Setting the property as a string will update the property when cleared.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by Veer in the comments above try using UpdateSourceTrigger as follows to detect when you change the text.  Set a break point in your view model and see if you capture the change events when you type in the text box.

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```